# using copy data for transport of data using data factory

Tags: azure, file, datatables, database-migration, factory

I need to pass a txt file using data copy to a database table. my text file is separated by pipe(|) but there are some dates within that file that are also being pipe-separated.
example: /Vig.2002|03|03
and so the data factory considers a number in each column to be something that is just garbage. Does anyone know how to solve this?

in the data set I use the pipe separator (|) for the columns

Comment: The question contains an example `/Vig.2002|03|03`. What is that supposed to become? It looks as if some fields are separated by `.`. Perhaps a more comprehensive example would help to clarify?

Comment: If you really have pipes _inside_ data fields, then you probably cannot guarantee success, unless such pipes only ever appear inside date fields (and nowhere else) - in which case you may be able to split by `|` and then re-join specific fields back into 1 field based on the field count. For example, fields 7, 8, and 9 must always be concatenated back into one field (a date value). But with data like this, the best answer is usually: **Go ask whoever produced your source data to fix how it is formatted.** (Or ask them how they would parse what they produced.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.